# vue3 / quasar: Inline condition (if/else) not working for scope.set for popup edit

Tags: if-statement, vuejs3, quasar-framework, quasar

I am using a q-popup-edit in vue3/quasar where I want to allow the submit on keyup.enter only if a given condition is true.

I am confused why this does not set the scope (nothing happens):

```
@keyup.enter="1==1 ? scope.set : ''" // Does not work
```

Why am I confused?
Firstly, the following prints "1" into the console, thus I can tell that the "console.log(1)" part after the "?" is executed.

```
@keyup.enter="1==1 ? console.log(1) : ''" // Works (prints "1")
```

Secondly, the following works, too, and it closes the popup-edit as expected:

```
@keyup.enter="scope.set" // Works (closes popup and sets value)
```

Since I only substitute the "console.log(1)" with "scope.set", I would expect this to work.
But nothing happens?!

Many thanks for your pointers

Answer (score 3):

Vue's event handler `v-on` can accept a function or a statement.  Given a function, it will be automatically invoked.  Given a statement that *includes* a function call you'll need to make sure to invoke it yourself using parenthesis, e.g. `scope.set()`

```js
@keyup.enter="1==1 ? scope.set() : ''"
```